# Can you solve this "- - - - -" puzzle? ("11001410002561n.a121")

Tags: pattern

### Replace the question marks with the correct number.

---

### A = n.a

### B = 1

### C = ?

### D = ?

### E = 150

### F = ?

### G = 100

### H = 121

### I = ?

### J = n.a

### K = 1

### L = ?

### M = ?

### N = ?

### O = 100

### P = 1

### Q = ?

### R = ?

### S = n.a

### T = ?

### U = n.a

### V = ?

### W = ?

### X = ?

### Y = n.a

### Z = n.a

---

*Note: All the "n.a's" are placed. You just have to focus on numbers. Also, no knowledge required other than trivial.*

Comment: I spotted something involving rot13(Ebzna ahzrenyf) but I suspect it's a red herring.

Comment: @EdMurphy Maybe, maybe not. Keep digging ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the missing values are as follows

> C = 100
>  D = 150500
>  F = 1
>  I = 1
>  L = 150
>  M = 1410002561
>  N = 121
>  Q = 100
>  R = 1
>  T = 1
>  V = 5
>  W = 55
>  X = 10

Reasoning

> The idea is to determine Roman numerals which form part of the capital letter, list them from left to right (ordered by the leftmost part first and then the rightmost part) and then convert back to decimal.
>  For example, the left vertical line of the "D" gives an "I" and there is also an "L" contained within it and, of course "D" itself so, from left to right, we have I,L,D which are the numerals for 1,50,500 and so we get 150500 as the value for D.
>  Letters like "H" are a bit tricky - we take the left vertical line representing "I" first then two vertical lines representing "II" and then the right vertical representing "I" again to get I,II,I or 121.
>  This caused a little bit of confusion when it came to "M" which contains "I" "II", "M", "IV", "V", "VI" and "I" again but the correct ordering (thanks to OP for explaining) is "I,IV,M,II,V,VI,I" which yields 1410002561
>  The title (in the brackets) is a conversion of the word **ROMAN**.

Thanks to Prim3numbah for clearing up my confusion with the letter M.

Comment: Aah, I forgot the "2" in M. Obvious miss there. And you're right I got the wrong ordering there, but it should be rot13(V, VI, Z, VV, I, IV, V. Tbvat sebz yrsg gb evtug. Jung pna lbh perngr sebz svefg yrt (V)... Lbh pna perngr V, gura VI, gura Z naq gura VV. Naq nsgre gung vg'f gur gjb qvntbany yrtf (I)... Lbh pna perngr I,  gura IV naq ynfgyl V.)

Comment: It got tricky with M, but it should be correct now. You'll get the tick anyways ofc.

Comment: @Prim3numbah That makes sense, thanks for clearing it up!